# How to create tabbed interface in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want create the tabbed interface in asp.net, for this i have searching in internet at finally i found a link below i paste that link please verify that.

i am using this link to create tabbed items but  this showing some errors like namespace are not found. Please help me where i can change to rectify this error.

Hope you can understand my problem please...

http://weblogs.asp.net/alessandro/archive/2008/01/05/tabmenu-missing-in-the-asp-net-toolbox-not-anymore.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can look at the ajax toolkit: http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/tabs/tabs.aspx

While I recomend to take a look at a [jquery solution](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=jquery%20tabs) if you know jquery well

And this is a way to create tabs without ajax or jquery: [A Simple ASP.NET Tab Control Using the MultiView control](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/custom-controls/TabControl.aspx)

Comment: Hi,Thank You for giving reply. Actually i'm not good in jquery ,and i want click event in code behind because when i click a tab then it will check some conditions based on condition display the grid in the appropriate panel.

Comment: Hi,I am trying that one also but in this image click event are not fire when i click on image there is no responce.

Comment: Hi, Can you give any idea how to register name space in .aspx page please.

Comment: add this to the top of the page: <%@ Import namespace=”System.Data” %>

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Amr ElGarhy I'd like to add [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/) .

Comment: Hi,Thank You for giving reply. Actually i'm not good in jquery ,and i want click event in code behind because when i click a tab then it will check some conditions based on condition display the grid in the appropriate panel

Answer (score 0):

You can also try free [ASP.NET Controls with Full AJAX Support](http://extaspnet.codeplex.com/) it works fine,

Comment: Hi Thank you giving response,i checked above link given by you,in this i find one page like Tabstrip in Grid folder.How can get main.css file  it showing some errors at <ext> tag .please help me.

Comment: You need to add settings in your WEB.CONFIG file as described http://extasp.net/#/extaspnet/config/modify_webconfig.htm Also you can install tool box in VS http://extasp.net/#/extaspnet/config/install_toolbox.htm

Comment: HI,Yes i can  change all things now it is working fine Thank you.But i have one issue that is in normal grid when i click the Editlink button  i can found the row id in behind code but here i'm using ext grid,How can i found row id when i click Editlink in this tool please help me.

Comment: Hi Adopilot ,How Can i find Tab click event when i click the tab display grid view in the panel based condition in code behind .Is it possible using this tool.Please Letme know click event if it possible.

Comment: I apologize to but I am  new bile in ASP.NET also in C# I do not think that I can give you correct answer, You shod open new SO

Comment: Also if you still want to use ASP.NET grid I think that in panel you can use Asp.net controls or HTML tags. http://extasp.net/#/extaspnet/layout/panel.aspx

Comment: Hi,i am using the grid control in that how to get Link button click event please tell me ... I can write code "Onclick" event but it is not fire the click event.